# Ex_machina changing data upon creation

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Here is my Factory (using the ex_machina package):

```
def question_factory do
    %Question{
      active: true,
      type: "NBA",
      description: "player points",
      reserved: %{
        information: %{
          game_id: Ecto.UUID.generate,
          player_id: Ecto.UUID.generate,
          player_name: "Lebron James"
        },
        inputs: [
          %{
            type: "text",
            label: "Player Points",
          }
        ]
      }
    }
end
```

#### Question Schema

```
schema "questions" do
  field(:active, :boolean)
  field(:type, :string)
  field(:description, :string)
  embeds_one(:reserved, Statcasters.Questions.Reserved)

  timestamps()
end
```

#### Reserved Schema

```
embedded_schema do
  field(:information, :map)
  field(:inputs, {:array, :map})
end
```

Here is my test setup:

```
question = insert(:question, reserved: %{ information: %{player_name: "steve"}})
```

In this example I want to `only` update the `player_name` for the `reserved` map. But when I use the above setup the question struct looks like this:

```
%MyApp.Question{
  __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "questions">,
  active: true,
  description: "player points",
  id: 125,
  inserted_at: ~N[2018-08-27 14:47:42.075169],
  reserved: %MyApp.Questions.Reserved{
    information: %{player_name: "steve"},
    inputs: nil
  },
  type: "NBA",
  updated_at: ~N[2018-08-27 14:47:42.075182]
}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
%MyApp.Question{
  __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "questions">,
  active: false,
  description: "player points",
  id: 122,
  inserted_at: ~N[2018-08-27 14:39:52.672051],
  reserved: %MyApp.Questions.Reserved{
    information: %{
      game_id: "1ab95979-329a-488c-9d5f-22bed4f2b985",
      player_id: "07cc1588-68eb-43b6-afa6-483fa3005cb2",
      player_name: "Steve"
    },
    inputs: [%{label: "Player Points", type: "text"}]
  },
  type: "NBA",
  updated_at: ~N[2018-08-27 14:39:52.672058]
}
```

Again, the problem is that it's replacing all of the values within `reserved` I want it just to change `player_name` how can I achieve this using Elixir and `ex_machina`?

Comment: please also post a schema for `MyApp.Question`

Comment: @denis.peplin Updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently explicitly tell `ex_machina` to set `reserved` as specified. When one needs to update the record, one should [`ExMachina.build/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_machina/ExMachina.html#c:build/2) it, update it, and save back. Or, alternatively, [`ExMachina.Ecto.insert/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_machina/ExMachina.Ecto.html#c:insert/2) the scaffold, and then update it, but this is not intended by `ex_machina`.

That said, the following should work.

```
:question
|> build()
|> put_in(~w|reserved information player_name|a, "steve")
|> insert()
```

See [*Flexible Factories with Pipes*](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_machina/readme.html#flexible-factories-with-pipes) for details.